# Default overload for ambiguous calls

Tags: c#, ambiguous-call

Say I have the following two functions:

```
void Foo(IEnumerable<string> bar)
{
  if(bar == null)
    return;
  foreach(var b in bar)
  {
    Console.Write(b);
  }
}
```

and

```
void Foo(string bar)
{
   Foo(new string[] { bar });
}
```

Those two are ambiguous if I'm passing `null` as a parameter.

Is there a way to hint the compiler to disambiguate the overload? Any attribute or directive or something?
In this case, I'd like the first function to be called. Something like:

```
[InCaseOfAmbiguityUseThis]
public void Foo(IEnumerable<string> bar)
```

So that if I `Foo(null)` the compiler will know where to look for and not complain.

I've been looking for a while and haven't found anything to the respect.

**PS:** I know I can use: `Foo((IEnumerable<string>)null)` but that's what I'm trying to avoid: the types in the real functions are quite long and use generic constraints (so I can't just inherit the type to make it shorter), so it dirties the code a lot.

I don't mind it being *'dirty'* in the libraries (where I'm specifying those functions) but not on the actual business code (where I'm calling those functions).

Also, there might be a lot of these possibly ambiguous functions, so "a workaround to not make them ambiguous" is out of the question (that's what I'm using now, but I don't like having such boilerplate code)

## Edit

I'm not looking for workarounds (i.e., making other functions with different or no parameters). I know all these ways, and as I specified, **I'm already using that**. Just wondering if it's actually possible to make the compiler disambiguate "automatically".

I'd prefer not to have a parameterless function (the real function is much more verbose passing a null parameter than passing no parameter at all):

```
Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> GetAsyncProjected<TResult>(
    IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> filters,
    Expression<Func<T, TResult>> projection,
    IEnumerable<string> eagerLoadRelationships,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken,
    ServiceRefreshMode refreshMode);

Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> GetAsyncProjected<TResult>(
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter,
    Expression<Func<T, TResult>> projection,
    IEnumerable<string> eagerLoadRelationships,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken,
    ServiceRefreshMode refreshMode);

// ... plenty of overloads for each possible parameter ...
```

I do have another overload for each of those overloads without the `filter`/`filters` parameter but I'd prefer not to so that the caller knows it's passing `null`  for the filter explcitly.

If there is no way, then I'll look for other ways (calling it `GetAsyncFilteredProjected()` if it has a parameter or something)

Comment: No, there isn't. It is only ambiguous if you are using a null literal when invoking the method. Consider why you want to pass a null literal so often. Perhaps you want a parameterless overload.

Comment: Another possible alternative is to declare the methods as `params string[]`, which allows the caller to supply any number of strings in-line, including none at all (with the drawback that you cannot pass an `IEnumerable` to it without first doing `.ToArray()`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert that would only be valid if the parameter is the last parameter of the function (in the "real" case, it's not)

Comment: Are you sure you are getting ambiguous error? I think it can't find the correct overload because it doesn't exist. Your line of code on `Foo(string)` is this: `Foo(new int[] { bar });` You can't pass `int[]` into an `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: @Jcl: you will, in general, get higher quality answers by posting the "real" case as your question. I don't think this particular case is so complicated that it needed to be simplified.

Comment: @TyCobb that was obviously a mistake when making the example

Comment: @JeroenMostert I made an edit with a sample

Comment: Rather than looking for a non existing mechanism to disambiguate the ambiguous, take this as an opportunity to redesign the interface. What you've got seems very confusing and complex. Any time you expect a caller to pass null is a flag indicating a possible code smell.

Comment: @EricLippert it actually makes a lot of sense in usage. I could just have them pass empty or single-element `IEnumerables` (that should be the default). Having an overload for a single object is a commodity for those cases (many) where the `filter` would be unique... having users not pass anything (i.e., an overload without the parameter) makes it non-verbose to the library user and I'd prefer them passing null explcitly.

Comment: @EricLippert that said, if *you* say there's no such mechanism, then I'll take your word for it :-)

Comment: @Jcl In your case, I'd consider creating `GetAsyncProjectedOptions` class. Or relying on named parameters. Your code sounds like a mess.

Comment: Well, there are ways to hint to the compiler but I don't think you'll like any of them. For example, put the less desired ambiguous overloads in a less derived class. C# disambiguation logic always prefers more to less derived.

Comment: Or, if the methods are static and the callers are in the class, put the callers and the more desired overloads in a nested class. C# disambiguation logic prefers closer to farther nesting.

Comment: @Jcl Everyone should take Eric's word when it comes to .NET =P

Comment: @Athari that would not help if I have to make helper functions (or constructors) for generating the `GetAsyncProjectedOptions` class. I'd be in the same problem unless I derive many types from that class (which I could just be doing from the class that has that `GetAsyncProjected` function).

Comment: @EricLippert they are not static. I guess I'll just remove the single-object call and for those cases have the user do `new[]{ filter }` (which would allow them to pass `null` if desired)

Comment: If you want it to be explicit, consider providing a `public const Foo EmptyFoo = null` and then encourage the caller to use the descriptive constant. This both resolves the ambiguity and makes the calling code readable.

Comment: @EricLippert in my case (since I'm using interfaces) a const is not possible, but I created a readonly property which does just that (`public IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> EmptyFilter { get { return (IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>) null; } }`). Now I do like that!

Comment: @Jcl: Excellent. Or, even better, `return Enumerable.Empty<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>();`, and actually represent an empty collection as an empty collection, rather than the absence of a collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to customize overloading in C# like this. There're strict rules of choosing a method overload.

However, if you want to provide a version of the method *without* the argument, you can just create a new overload instead of passing `null`:

```
void Foo()
{
    Foo((string)null);
}
```

It would be more readable, as a bonus.

Also, if you can't modify original classes and they don't provide overloads you need, you can use extension methods. This will keep business logic clean.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, it's precisely what I want to avoid

Comment: @Jcl It isn't clear from the question whether you create overloads or cast null to specific types when you call methods. The first way is *the* way of avoiding ambiguity in C#.

Comment: I'm currently already doing the parameterless overload. In this particular case, I'd prefer not to have a parameterless overload, but if it's not possible, then so be it.

Anyway, the question was clear: is it possible to hint the compiler to disambiguate automatically? If it's not possible, then I know all the "workarounds".

Comment: @Jcl See the first parapgraph then. The answer is no. Such an attribute would be close to impossible to implement. Consider having methods A, B, C; one call is ambigous between A and B (and you prefer A), another is ambigous between B and C (and you prefer B). How would you decorate the methods with your attribute?

Comment: I was afraid the answer was "no", and I had foreseen those possible ambiguities, but there's lots of not-so-known features in C# and a brighter mind than I could have thought of a solution (that's why I use stackoverflow ;-) )

Comment: Accepted as answer because the first paragraph is true (I was hoping it wasn't :-) )